# cannot find module in electron prebuilt 1.x but in 0.x (0.2 and 0.3

Tags: module, electron

I have a small code, that run well in electron (using prebuild 0.3.5, and 0.25).

I upgrade to electron prebuild 1.1.0 and 1.2.0

I got error

Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'app'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/mervo/electron/midas-tron/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:47:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (/ho

I think there is a change in structure in 1.x, that I dont know, can help?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to require the `app` module in Electron v1.0.0+ is:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
```

The same applies to any other built-in Electron module you could previously require directly.